# Counting the occurances of a word in a sentence in C

Tags: c, string

As mentioned in the heading, I am having problems while extracting a word from a sentence. It is giving a "break-point error". Can anyone help me understand how am I messing up, as I am just a beginner.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char* word_array[50],  input[51],  word[51], temp[51];
    short i , j, k, flag;
    i = j = k = flag = 0;
    printf("Enter the sentence (max 50 characters):\n");
    gets_s(input, 50);
    printf("\nEnter the word to be searched : ");
    gets_s(word, 50);

    while (input[i] != NULL)
    {
        while (input[i] == ' ')// skip the spaces
            i = i + 1;

        k = 0;
        while (input[i] != ' ' || input[i] != NULL)//extract the words
        {
            word_array[j] = (char*)malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
            *(*(word_array + j) + k) = input[i];
            k = k + 1;
            i = i + 1;
        }
        *(*(word_array + j) + k) = '\0';
        printf("\nProcessed word : %s", word_array[j]);//just for debugging
        j = j + 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= j; i++)
        if (strcmp(word_array[i], word) == 0)
            flag = flag + 1;

    printf("\nThe word occurred in the sentence %hu times.\n\n", flag);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Break-point error]

Comment: Does your programming environment provide a debugger? I think you need to single-step through the program, checking the values of the relevant variables at each stage. I think expecting other people to do that for you is hoping for a lot, although there are a few contributors with that level of generosity.

Comment: I am not asking anybody to DEBUG entire program for me, just trying to understand "what is a breakpoint?" (internet does not provide a satisfactory answer) and why is it giving that error, when I am not noticing any problem. Thank you for the wisdom, though!

Comment: `while (input[i] != ' ' || input[i] != NULL)` - think  really hard about that for  a moment. Since `input[i]` can never be *both* of those values (space and null) simultaneously, one of those expressions will always be true. and with the OR applied, the overall expression will therefore always be true. I.e. you have an infinite loop.

Comment: A breakpoint is an instruction to a debugger to stop at a particular point. I guess that your programming environment has generated a breakpoint automatically, and stopped the program, because of a memory corruption. My guess is that something in your program writes to an address that has not been allocated, and the whole memory block chain is corrupt. I don't know of any obvious way forward, except for careful analysis of the program alongside single-stepping or value tracing. However, somebody smarter than me might spot the problem straight away.

Comment: @WhozCraig thanx man, you correctly pointed out the logical error which was destroying my programs. This has improved by string handling logic. Really appreciate it.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [Visual Studio debugger documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/?view=vs-2019)